# Two drives with the same drive letter

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I shrunk my D drive by 30 GB, and chose "Extend" on the free space, adding it to E drive. Now I have two E drives as shown in the picture below...

[image: Disk Management capture]

Is this normal/okay? If not, how can I combine them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No.  You still have *one* `E:` volume.  It's just in two pieces on the disc.

`Psycogeek` is wrong.  The text description *does* match the graphics.  Xe has not paid enough attention to what is clearly written there.  Even though Disk Manager has told you in that screenshot no fewer than *five* times that this is a dynamic, not a basic, disc, you've both still overlooked this.  Moreover, Disk Manager is clearly saying that the text list is a list of *volumes*, not of the underlying disc slices.  You have one `E:` volume, and it is listed once.

You [extended a simple volume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb727122.aspx#XSLTsection125121120120) into another slice of the disc, so now Disk Manager is diagrammatically showing you the two slices of the disc that, when concatenated, make up the whole of the *single* volume.  Some simple arithmetic confirms that, indeed, 128 is 30 plus 98.

And because of the way that you've done this, the slices are in reverse order. The first (30GiB) piece on the disc is actually the *second* part of the actual volume.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to combine them without losing data?

Comment: @Jim, there's no need.  The existing layout is fine.

Comment: As M. Johnston says: They are *already* combined into a single volume.  All that rearranging the disc slices would really get you is a slightly simpler diagram in Disk Manager.  The simplest way to achieve that, if you *really* want to do it despite it having little concrete benefit, would involve duplicating, deleting, and re-creating the volume; which is done in the obvious ways.